# Amplify datastore "Unauthorized" error on custom auth identityClaim

Tags: aws-amplify, datastore

When I change the identityClaim field in my model, I got the error ""Unauthorized","message":"Not Authorized to access..." when I try to start Datastore in the app.

But, it works as expected when I run the query in AWS AppSync.(It saves the groupID in owner field)

Here is the configuration:

```
type Book
 @model
 @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, identityClaim: "custom:groupID" }]) {
 id: ID!
 name: String!
 owner: Strin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this same issue and resolved it by using the `graphql_headers` `Amplify.config` option to override the default datastore Authorization header. it was using the Access token by default, but to use a custom cognito attribute as the identity claim, you need to use the ID token, because those custom attributes aren’t present on the Access token (i documented all the gory details in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/9058)). in my app, it looks like:

```
Amplify.configure({
    ...awsconfig,
    // https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3794
    graphql_headers: async () => {
        try {
            const token = (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken();
            return { Authorization: token };
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            return {};
        }
    },
});
```

---

note that your `owner` field has a typo (`Strin` → `String`), but i’m guessing that’s just a copy/paste issue.